# PTIJ: Tattooing a self-aware Sefer Torah

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If a Sefer Torah became self-aware and conscious, would such a Sefer Torah be Halachically allowed to get ink tattooed into it when needed (such as correcting cracked letters)? Or would this constitute [getting a tattoo](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.28)?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Can't letters get erased or chipped? That doesn't sound like a tattoo.

Answer (score 5):

The Vilna Gaon says that the *klei shares* in the *mishkan* were sentient. He says that this is so because sentience is a function of *kedushah*, and therefore since the *klei shares* had the *kedushah* of the *benei yisrael* they too were sentient.

See for example:
[image]
[image]

(**Note**: I think I saw this gr"a concerning the *klei ha'mishkan* but I can't find that reference at the moment.)

Furthermore, see Rashi https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%90

> ובכלי שרת - בלבוש בגדי כהונה

And we know there was writing on some *bigdei kehunah*, such as the *tzitz*. Therefore it is evident that there is no *issur* of tattooing for a sentient *sefer torah*.

It may be advisable to consult the *sefer torah*'s therapist beforehand, however.

Comment: The proof from the tzitz is weak, though. First of all, the writing was done before it had its kedushah (the question would be whether letters can be corrected on it later on). Second, they were protruding, and the issur of כתובת קעקע is when they're etched into the skin.

Comment: @Meir I had a vague recollection that for some reason there were some *klei shares* that were marked with a letter, but I couldn't find it. Not sure if I imagined this.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the choshen. I think it says that they inscribed the letters on the stones with ink and then had the shamir go over them to engrave them, though I can't find that at the moment.

Comment: @Meir No, I was thinking of some *klei shares* that they marked so they would what type of blood it had in it.

Comment: Ah. The Mishnah (Maaser Sheni 4:10-11) mentions vessels labeled with the word "korban" or with an initial, such as מ for maaser or ד for demai, but it doesn't look like that's talking about klei shareis.

Comment: @Meir Ich hob a to'us.

Comment: Where does the graw write this? I'd actually like to see it

Comment: @bluejayke Added to the answer

Comment: @the wow that is actually fascinating, would make sense regarding the aygil etc

Comment: @the seemingly is that only talking about the krooveem though which had the face of people, or did the same apply to the meezbayawch etc?

Comment: @bluejayke Yes I know which is why I would have preferred to send the one about the *klei ha'mishkan* but I can't find this at the moment and I do not think I imagined it although anything is possible.

Comment: @the well if they can imagine... ;)

Comment: You have got to find that Gr"a about klei shareis; I would love to see it.

Answer (score 2):

As shocking as it may sound, a sentient sefer torah was not part of the bris at Sinai, and consequently is not obligated in Mitzvot, so giving it a Tatoo would be no problem. However, if the torah undergoes milah and tevilah, it would be a problem.

Comment: How could a sentient sefer torah undergo tevilah? It would violate the prohibition to erase the name

Comment: This is all well and good for an Ashkenazi sefer Torah, which very clearly has a yesod upon which Brit Milah may be performed, but what about a Sefardi one?