# PTIJ: Who is Rue?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

> וְהָיָה לָכֶם לְצִיצִת וּרְאִיתֶם אֹתוֹ וּזְכַרְתֶּם אֶת כָּל מִצְוֹת יְהֹוָה וַעֲשִׂיתֶם אֹתָם ***וְלֹא תָתֻרוּ*** אַחֲרֵי לְבַבְכֶם וְאַחֲרֵי עֵינֵיכֶם אֲשֶׁר אַתֶּם זֹנִים אַחֲרֵיהֶם

It clearly says here "וְלֹא תָתֻרוּ": Do not tattoo Rue. So, the question is, who exactly is Rue? And why can we not tattoo him/her?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Rue is a sentient Sefer Torah. See here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120253/ptij-tattooing-a-self-aware-sefer-torah/120275

Answer (score 8):

Because Roo is too young to give consent, and his mother Kanga doesn't allow it. Obviously.

They daven at the Agudah of the 20 [Beis-Kor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_and_Talmudic_units_of_measurement#Area) Woods.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone knows that this is a prohibition to deface Australian wildlife.

Answer (score 4):

A "rue" is a kind of street. The prohibition is to tell us that even if we have a poor memory for maps, we cannot tattoo maps on our bodies. Scars or birthmarks are okay, though, as Chief Rabbi Dumbledore said ([Hilchot Potter, Vol. I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher%27s_Stone)):

> "'Yes,' said Dumbledore. 'He'll have that scar for ever.'
>
> 'Couldn't you do something about it, Dumbledore?'
>
> 'Even if I could, I wouldn't. Scars can come in useful. I have one myself above my left knee which is a perfect map of the London underground.'"

Answer (score 2):

Rue's last name is Acharei. Rue tattooed both his heart and his eyes.

Answer (score 2):

B"H

It actually depends on the Awshkinawzik or Sifawrdik pronunciations, according to chabad minhug, it's "sawsoorroo", or "saw, sue roo!" that rue was actually getting sued, for sawing unlawfully, because he could see what he saw, and used the C-saw to cause damage to the sea by splitting it, which the nation of Yisroyayl saw, like it says "loy sawsoor, rue!", that Hashem is telling Rue not to sawsoor,  destroy, any more property, with the saw that he could see, like it says "after your eyes", right after

Blessings and success

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulitzer_Prize_for_Poetry

Answer (score 1):

Takka, there is a different source with an opposite drasha, that you davka should tattoo rue:

When we say in hataras nedarim: *v'ein any soehi, chas veshalom*, the Chabad siddur translates: *I do not rue, Heaven forfend, my doing good deeds!*

A synonym for regret is *charata*.

*Cheret* can also mean "a sharp tool", as one pshat in Rashi has about Aharon using to make the Golden Calf.

And everyone knows you do use a sharp tool to make tattoos!

Hamlet's mother held like this drasha instead; that's why she wore her rue, with a difference -- i.e. aware that there was a machlokes about it.